# From where we can view earth moving?

Tags: orbital-motion, earth, speed

Earth moves with a speed around $100000 \,\,km/h$, which will be amazing, but from where we can see that moving speed? If we far away from earth (outside of earth gravity) then can view its moving? is any video already taken? (I failed to search that kind of video)

Comment: that velocity is relative to the sun.

Comment: Really? You expect a video of this!!?  I suspect trolling, but I gave a reasonable answer nonetheless.

Comment: You can see the earth moving if you are not moving with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All speeds are relative.  In this case the 100 Mm/h (haven't verified that, taking your word on it) is relative to the solar system as a whole.  Therefore, you can "see" this speed from any place where you are in a fixed position relative to the solar system.  For example, if you could park yourself 93 Mmiles off the predominant plane of the solar system directly perpendicular to the sun, you'd see earth going around in a circle spanning about 90° of your view.  The earth would take one year to complete this circle, and it would move at the 100 Mm/h speed.  It would be rather boring to watch, and just a dot without a telescope anyway.